# Why I'm getting "Refusing to install purify-css as a dependency of itself" error?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss) library to get only css rules that are used. The documantation says I should use this command but when I use it, I receive the following error:

```
npm install --save purify-css

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "purify-css"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install purify-css as a dependency of itself
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/fatih/Downloads/purifycss-master/npm-debug.log
```

When I go to the root directory of this project and use this command I receive this error:

```
bin/purifycss

Error: Cannot find module 'yargs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fatih/Downloads/purifycss-master/bin/purifycss:3:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I would appreciate any help!

[Refusing to install purify-css as a dependency of itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXSZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gulp, or grunt, or webpack?
I'm using gulp and also when I tried to install were issues.

purify-css - is not correct for gulp, for example. For gulp needs to use:
gulp-purifycss (there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purifycss a bit wrong because var purify = require('gulp-purify'); is not correct, correct here https://github.com/purifycss/gulp-purifycss).

I hope this will help.

Comment: What do you mean by " var purify = require('gulp-purify') is not correct " - the link you provided seems to show the same line of code? I am getting the error "Cannot find module 'gulp-purifycss' (Gulp), any advice?